# Ruby access array values

Tags: ruby

I'm reading from a file say - list.txt and check if strings from list.txt are present in multiple files in a directory.
(E:\work...). Below is my code, its working as expected.

```
pool = ''
rows = Array[]
id_files = Dir.glob("E:\work'*-access.txt")

value=File.open('E:\nando\list.txt').read
value.each_line do |line|
    line.chomp!
    id_files.each do |file_name|
      text = File.read(file_name)
      new_content = text.gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\s/, '').gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}/, '' )

      unless text == new_content

        text.each_line do |li|
          if li.match(/#{Regexp.escape(line)}/) then
           rows << li # I didn't complete the array part
            puts rows[0]
            puts rows[1]
           pool = li.split(" ")[0] 
          end
        end 
        File.open('E:\Removed_users.txt', 'a') { |log| 
        log.puts "Removed from: #{file_name}"
        log.puts "Removed id : #{line}"
        log.puts "Removed from row :#{pool}"
        log.puts "*" * 50 
        }
        File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts new_content }
      end
    end
end
```

I'm trying to enhance the code to print in the below format to a log file.Eg for strings - class\234ha and cap\7y6t5 from one of the file in the directory.

```
Removed class\234ha from row = id and dept
Removed cap\7y6t5 from row = id
```

E:\work\sample-access.txt

```
CDA created on September 20th 1999
Owner: Edward Jenner
Access IDs,
id = class\234ha, class\poi23, class\opiuj, cap\7y6t5
dept = sub\6985de, ret\oiu87, class\234ha
rec = ret\oiu87
```

I'm able to make it print only for a single time.i.e. for class\234ha I'm getting output as

```
Removed from: E:\work\sample-access.txt
Removed user : class\234ha
Removed from row = id
```

ideally it should be

```
Removed from: E:\work\sample-access.txt
Removed user : class\234ha
Removed from row = id and dept
```

I tried using array options but I'm not getting the result as expected and I don't want to totally rewrite the code or logic. Ruby experts, any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the simplest solution (with minimal changes) to your question is

```
# ... your code
pool = [] # define array for current match
text.each_line do |li|
  # ... your code
  pool << li.split(" ")[0] # add to array
# ... your code
log.puts "Removed from row :#{pool.join(' and ')}" # list all the ids joined by and
# ... your code
```

I hope I didnt overlook something

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but Its appending the values like below instead of printing single value per row

`Removed from : sample-access.txt
Removed from row : id 
Removed from : sample-access.txt
Removed from row : id and dep

Removed from : rate-access.txt
Removed from row :  dep and automation`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the comment (possibly because of formating in comments). For each line (= id) it keeps all the sections it was removed from for current file in loop - `pool` contains sections (= row) per file. I based the answer on _ideally it should be_ from your question.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I got it worked in a different fashion.